# Strange Security Settings Windows Server 2016

Tags: apache-http-server, windows-server-2016

So I've been trying to install XAMPP and run it on my Windows Server 2016 environment, and the version of Windows Server I'm on seems to have a whole bunch of strange security settings. So, upon trying to install XAMPP I was greeted with an error message saying "Because an activated user account User Account on your system some functions of XAMPP are possibly restricted." So, I tried disabling the UAC settings as it suggested, but I still got the error. I continued with the install and now I'm getting a whole bunch of errors while trying to run apache, like this:

```
4:27:47 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
4:27:47 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
4:27:47 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
4:27:47 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
4:27:47 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
```

I'm sure it's the weird security settings this machine has. Is there some way I can check and disable some of these security features? They're really quite annoying and getting in the way.

**EDIT**
Forgot to include error.log

```
[Tue Nov 14 16:26:56.857893 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 2180:tid 544] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\php.ini on line 709
3:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 14 16:26:57.186056 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2180:tid 544] AH00455: Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/5.6.32 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 14 16:26:57.186056 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2180:tid 544] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Oct 23 2017 12:17:08
[Tue Nov 14 16:26:57.186056 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2180:tid 544] AH00094: Command line: 'apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Program Files (x86)/xampp/apache'
[Tue Nov 14 16:26:57.201750 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2180:tid 544] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1020
Apache server shutdown initiated...
sl:warn] [pid 1020:tid 528] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\php.ini on line 709
3:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 14 16:26:58.764107 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1020:tid 528] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Nov 14 16:27:03.045467 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2180:tid 544] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Nov 14 16:27:05.076607 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1020:tid 528] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Nov 14 16:27:05.107828 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2180:tid 544] AH00430: Parent: Child process 1020 exited successfully.
[Tue Nov 14 16:27:08.530385 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 4240:tid 508] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\php.ini on line 709
3:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 14 16:27:08.842405 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4240:tid 508] AH00455: Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/5.6.32 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 14 16:27:08.842405 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4240:tid 508] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Oct 23 2017 12:17:08
[Tue Nov 14 16:27:08.842405 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4240:tid 508] AH00094: Command line: 'apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Program Files (x86)/xampp/apache'
[Tue Nov 14 16:27:08.858036 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4240:tid 508] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4500
[Tue Nov 14 16:27:10.404739 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 4500:tid 516] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\php.ini on line 709
3:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 14 16:27:10.701602 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4500:tid 516] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

And another thing, my Arma 3 server is having some troubles connecting to my database. Maybe this has something to do with the permissions as well?

Comment: You received an error but I can’t tell if you provided us that error or not, which isn’t good, because now I just sit here wondering “what’s the error?”

Comment: I included the error log for apache. Idk what any of it means tho

Comment: I agree that the question could be clearer, but the first line of the first preformatted (code) clock says “Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.”, so that is probably the OP’s primary concern.

Comment: It also says “check the Windows Event Viewer” for more information.  Fix your syntax error in your php.ini file